# If a matrix $\boldsymbol{\mathrm {A}}$ is orthogonal, its determinant is $\pm 1$. Is the converse also true?

Tags: matrices, analytic-geometry

I know that an orthogonal matrix satisfies $$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\boldsymbol{\mathrm {AA}}^T=\boldsymbol{\mathrm {A}}^T\boldsymbol{\mathrm {A}}=\boldsymbol{\mathrm {I}}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(*)$$
and that as a consequence of this, $\det \boldsymbol{\mathrm {A}}=\pm 1$. I also know that if $\det \boldsymbol{\mathrm {A}}=+1$, then $\boldsymbol{\mathrm {A}}\in\mathrm {SO}(n)$, i.e. it is a *rotation*, and that if $\det \boldsymbol{\mathrm {A}}=-1$, then it is a *reflection*. The issue is:

> if I know that the determinant of a matrix is $\pm 1$, do I have to
>   verify $(*)$ above, or can I conclude straight away that it is orthogonal, an isometry and a rotation/reflection?

Comment: $$\begin{bmatrix}\alpha & 1\\ 0 & \alpha^{-1}\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: think to the determinant as the (oriented) volume of $Im(Cube)$ the image by $A$ of the unit (hyper)cube in dimension $n$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Volume_and_Jacobian_determinant

Answer (score 5):

What can you say about
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
3&0\\
0&\frac{1}{3}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Counterexample:

\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 1 \\
    3 & 2 
  \end{bmatrix}

Orthogonal matrices have the form:

\begin{bmatrix}
    cos(\theta) & - sin(\theta) \\
    sin(\theta) & cos(\theta) 
  \end{bmatrix}